# How can I copy the URL of a file downloaded by Google Chrome?

Tags: finder, google-chrome

As a new Mac user, I'm surprised to see that Chrome doesn't track the list of downloaded files anymore. I can't even see the current download speed in the Finder.

I want to copy the URL of a file being downloaded, because I want to download it from another machine, in turn because the network I'm currently connected to is just too slow. How can this be done?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Chrome **does** show you a list of all your downloads. Just press the square "lines" image in the top right hand corner and select "Downloads". Or when you are downloading something, you will see the downloads bar at the bottom. On the right hand section of the bar should be a button allowing you to see all the downloads.

Comment: ^ I'm really surprised that it doesn't show anything. The Downloads page is _blank_! Also, I already closed the window I downloaded the file with. The download bar at the bottom only shows the files downloaded in that same window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selecting the file and doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> will bring up the file's *Info*. Under the *More Info* section you'll find the **Where From** information, which is the URL where the file was downloaded from.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal equivalent would be:

```
xattr -l download.zip
```

or for all files in a dir (with `.` being the current dir):

```
xattr -lr .
```

**[xattr](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html)**'s output is not easy to copy since it displays the data as binary.

For copy-paste friendly output use [**mdls**](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdls.1.html):

```
mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms -raw download.zip
```